# Trying to understand server response that returns a javascript method

Tags: javascript, php

I've seen this code today and I cannot understand why someone had to write something like this. It seems that this returns a javascript method. But why? How is that useful? Why not return the {id:123} immediately? The expiration date is the same as the Date but why? To prevent caching?

```
    <?php
       header('Content­Type: text/plain');
       header('Expires: Tue, 30 Aug 2015 16:03:37 GMT');
       header('Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2015 16:03:37 GMT');
       header('Connection: close');
       echo "do({id:123})";
    ?>
```

Comment: Looks like a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP which has allready been linked has to do with circumventing something called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) in JavaScript and it is a way to prevent malicious code to for example controlling the DOM of your page.

Now this becomes a problem when you want to use let's say a webservice like flickr or facebook or whatever from your JS-code, doing fancy ajax-requests and stuff. 
So meet JSONP. With JSONP you basically inject a script-tag into your page, because this is okay according to the above mentioned policy. in your case the "js-script" is:

```
do({id:123});
```

Which makes it possible for you to define the function `do` and thus using the response from the remote service. Usually you're able to pass the name of the desired name for the callback in the url, so if you don't recognize `do` it's probably the default.

When it comes to the expirationdate, you're most probably right that is to prevent caching.

Answer (score 0):

It's [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), maybe not exactly, because you are not able to set callback, but something like this. It runs JS function after the script is loaded.